# Compiling with maven UTF-8 encoded source files fails

Tags: java, maven, utf-8

I am using maven to build a project. The source files are UTF-8 encoded. My pom.xml (relevant fragments) is like this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <JAVA_1_8_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121</JAVA_1_8_HOME>
</properties>

...

    <plugins>

        <!-- to compile not with default JAVA_HOME but custom path -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>${JAVA_1_8_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                <compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
...
    </plugins>
```

Now I have read the numerous posts/questions on the subject but none of the suggestions worked. I have tried setting encoding explicitly on maven-compiler-plugin but it still does not work. The error I get is:

```
[ERROR] *my source file - name removed*.java:[523,182] error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1253
[ERROR] *my source file - name removed*.java:[523,189] error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1253
```

However maven-resources-plugin does pick up project.build.sourceEncoding:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ XXXXXXXXXX ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
```

The only way I could get the project to compile was to set `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`.

I have tried maven v3.3.9 and 3.5.0 - no change.

Comment: Is there any relationship between `<compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>` and source encoding? something like 1.3 does not allow `UTF-8`. Can we have 1.8 there?

Comment: This DID resolve my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are configuring the default Maven behaviour in (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You say that you set `project.build.sourceEncoding` to UTF-8 in your pom.xml, However the error messages say that the encoding is Cp1253.  The configuration error is not in the snippet you posted.  Can you post a more complete version of your pom.xml?

---

You have to set the value UTF-8 to either the `project.build.sourceEncoding` property or the `encoding` element in one of the following 2 ways:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: I see you have <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> in your original pom.xml.  I have no idea why it does not work then

Comment: The full pom.xml is 100 lines. Any way I can add this at the end of the question collapsed (like a spoiler)?

Comment: Try to find out where the cp1253 encoding is coming from.  I tried your maven-compiler-plugin locally on my laptop with different encodings and it works as expected if `project.build.sourceEncoding` is set.  I think there is something wrong in the configuration that changes the value of this property to cp1253.

Comment: cp1253 is the platform (windows') default ANSI codepage. However @Pete nailed it. It seems setting compilerVersion to 1.3 prevents maven-compiler-plugin from passing the encoding to the Java compiler (hence the platform default encoding is used).

Comment: Good you found the issue.  I did not test against compilerVersion 1.3.  Java is backward compatible, so increase the compiler version.  I did not expect the behaviour because Java is written in unicode since the beginning (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1), I thought it would be able to handle UTF-8 in early versions as well.

Answer (score -2):

Hiii,, 
i did have a problem like that once; add this to your pom.xml file and see if it work:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Or there is an other way is to add envirnoment variable called JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, 
set this variable to: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

more about JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: [docs.oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/envvars-138887.html#gbmsy)

Comment: Please read the question more carefully. I have already tried your suggestion and it does not work. And I have already said that JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is the only way I could make it work (but it causes trouble elsewhere)

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of the `project.build.sourceEncoding` property to UTF-8?  It should work.